# Borel Measures: Single-Valued

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$.

Consider the Dirac measure:
$$\mu_\lambda(A):=\chi_A(\lambda)$$

Then it attains only zero and one:
$$\mu_\lambda(A)=0,1$$

Are there any other such measures?

Comment: What exactly do you want??

Comment: @John I suspect a proof that a non-trivial measure on the Borelsets of $\mathbb C$ that only takes values $0$ and $1$ will be a [Dirac-measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_measure) $\delta_z$ for some $z\in\mathbb C$.

Comment: That's true. For such a measure must has support at a point. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(measure_theory)

Comment: And (since the complex plane is 2nd countable), a nonzero measure has nonempty support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same proof, less technical.  Suppose $\mu$ is a measure taking exactly values $0,1$.  We claim $\mu$ is a dirac measure.

Let $U$ be the union of all open sets of measure zero.  Since $\mathbb C$ is 2nd countable, $U$ is the union of coutably many open sets of measure zero, so $\mu(U) = 0$.  Let $F$ be the complement of $U$.  Then $F$ has measure $1$.  I claim that $F$ is a singleton.  If not, there are two points $x \ne y$ in $F$, and thus there are disjoint open neighborhoods $U_x, U_y$ of them.  Since $U_x$ is not a subset of $U$, $\mu(U_x) = 1$.  Similarly $\mu(U_y)=1$.  So in fact $\mu(\mathbb C) \ge 2$ a contradiction.  Thus $F$ is a singleton, $\mu(F)=1$, $\mu(\mathbb C \setminus F) = 0$.

So I guess the point of doing another proof is: you don't need the exact structure of $\mathbb C$, merely that it is a 2nd countable Hausdorff space.

Comment: First of all thanks for the very nice proof!!
Can you explain: Why is $U$ the union of countably many open sets of measure zero?

Comment: Use the 2nd countable property: there is a countable base for the topology.  In the union making up $U$, each open set of measure zero is equal to the union of (countably many) open sets from the base.  Then $U$ itself is the union of all those sets from the base that were used; still only countably many of them.

Comment: Ah right thanks!! *(I always struggle with that argument.)*

Answer (score 0):

No.

If $\mu$ is a non-trivial measure on the Borelsets of $\mathbb C$ that only takes values in $\{0,1\}$ then for $n\in\{1,2,\dots\}$ there is a unique set  $A_n:=\{x+yi\mid m2^{-n}\leq x<(m+1)2^{-n}\wedge k2^{-n}\leq y<(k+1)2^{-n}\}$ with $\mu(A_n)=1$ and $k,m\in\mathbb Z$. This because these sets form a partition of $\mathbb C$ so that only one of them can have measure $1$. More than one leads to $\mu(\mathbb C)>1$ and less than one to (trivial) $\mu(\mathbb C)=0$.

Also we have $A_{1}\supset A_{2}\supset\cdots$ and their intersection (it cannot be empty because its measure is $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu(A_n)=1$) is a singleton $\{z\}$. That leads to $\mu=\delta_z$.